# Weird characters in html text

Tags: html, apache

I am developing a website with a web font that runs on apache.

On google chrome on android (desktop and ios is fine) I am seeing those weird characters. I first thought of an encoding problem, but those characters are not replacing any character they just popup in between characters.

How to solve that?

[image]

---

Solved: I had hidden characters in the text. Probably from copy pasting it. Removed it and wrote it again by hand.

Comment: Have you tried dumping the data through `od` or the like?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: What's od ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details, it's a bit harder to tell.

One way to diagnose this problem is to use a command like `od` to perform a data dump on the index file and finding out what is holding up that space.

You can perform that by running: `cat index.html | od -cb` for example and receive and output that will look like this:

```
    0000000    <   h   t   m   l   >  \n           <   b   o   d   y   >  \n
              074 150 164 155 154 076 012 040 040 074 142 157 144 171 076 012
    0000020                    <   p   >   S   a   f   e   t   y       a   n
              040 040 040 040 074 160 076 123 141 146 145 164 171 040 141 156
    0000040    d       s   e   c   u   r   i   t   y       a   r   e       p
              144 040 163 145 143 165 162 151 164 171 040 141 162 145 040 160
    0000060    r   i   o   r   i   t   y       o   n   e   <   /   p   >  \n
              162 151 157 162 151 164 171 040 157 156 145 074 057 160 076 012
    0000100            <   /   b   o   d   y   >  \n   <   /   h   t   m   l
              040 040 074 057 142 157 144 171 076 012 074 057 150 164 155 154
    0000120    >  \n
              076 012
    0000122
```

Then you'll be able to better determine what is going on.

Comment: You were on the right track. I had hidden characters.